# Log4j - logging of internal Log4j events

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am having some issue with log4j settings.

In order to solve them i have enabled internal log4j logging in log4j properties as that:

```
log4j.debug=true
```

It is working as i am getting logs like this in console which is fine:

```
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[DEBUG, console, rollingFile, test].
log4j: enter code here`: Level token is [DEBUG].
log4j: Category root set to DEBUG
log4j: Parsing appender named "console".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "console".
```

Now i need to save those logs also to file. 
I have added FileAppender which works for other logs, but does not save the internal log4j logs.

Whole log4j configuration:

```
#log4j.category.org.hibernate=INFO, hibernate 
log4j.category.org.hibernate.SQL=ERROR, hibernate 
#log4j.category.org.hibernate.type=ALL, hibernate
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.SQL=false

#Root logger setting
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, console, rollingFile, test

#Appenders configurations.
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.rollingFile=eu.unicorn.pcr.broker.logging.CustodianDailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=${catalina.home}/logs/pcr-app.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxNumberOfDays=10
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

#apender for stress request logging
log4j.appender.stressTest=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stressTest.File=${catalina.home}/logs/requests.log
log4j.appender.stressTest.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.stressTest.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stressTest.layout.conversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] - %m%n

log4j.category.stressTestLogger=TRACE, stressTest
log4j.additivty.stressTestLogger=false

log4j.appender.hibernate=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.hibernate.File=${catalina.home}/logs/hibernate.log
log4j.appender.hibernate.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.hibernate.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.hibernate.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.hibernate.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

# Define the test file appender 
log4j.appender.test=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.test.File=${catalina.home}/logs/test.log
log4j.appender.test.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.test.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.test.Append=false
log4j.appender.test.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.test.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n

log4j.debug=true
```

Any tips how to set up that the internal log4j logs will be also saved also in file? Would be glad for any hints.

Comment: Could you please share your logger config?

Comment: @AleksandrSemyannikov i have added the whole log4j.properties. The appender "test" is the one im trying to use to save the internal log4j events

Comment: @JanDryml Log4J uses System out/err for it's internal logging (See [LogLog](https://github.com/apache/log4j/blob/7be00eed88152dd011a619e8bae5a631235c3f4c/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/helpers/LogLog.java)). So it's not possible to log the internal logging to a log file unless you do some kind console output redirection to a file.

Comment: @Ramu thanks, the redirectionI worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want save your log in a file you must use the propierties for that.

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

# Set the immediate flush to true (default)
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

# Set the threshold to debug mode
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug

# Set the append to false, overwrite
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Comment: i have added the FileAppender settings, it is working perfectly fine for other logs then the internal log4j events mentioned before (e.g.: 
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[DEBUG, console, rollingFile, test].)

Comment: I have tried your solution and it does not log the internal log4j events neither

Comment: Im suppose it is on debug level (i also tried to set root level to TRACE, and also the FileAppender threshold to trace, does not works). But i am not sure as it is logged by log4j itself

Comment: Hi folks, please, log4j is open source, you can step through the initialization code of log4j very easy and see how it works. Would be much better than just guessing, and would avoid a lot of noise in stack overflow.